# How to navigate through Chrome bookmark folders easily?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have a bookmark folder with about 500 website bookmarks.
Every time I want to find a certain bookmark, I have to scroll through the *entire* folder until I can finally get the bottom or find the bookmark I want.

Is there any better way because I have to spend quite a long time finding a bookmark?

Thank you.

Comment: Use sorts and search to organize links into directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening the folder (from the bookmarks bar), type the first letter of the title of the bookmark - and keep typing it till you hit the correct bookmark.
As suggested, sorting would help here too.

Of course, pressing ctrl+shift+o (assuming Windows) to open chrome:bookmarks and then typing some part of the bookmark title/url may be faster if you don't know/remember the first letter of the title.